# Is it possible to specify an anonymous function to be called from onEvent in Autohotkey 2?

Tags: autohotkey

I am wondering if I can specify an anonymous function to be called with `onEvent` in Autohotkey V2.

The following, *not working*, script tries to outline what I try to achieve:

```
g := guiCreate()

txt := g.add('text', 'w200 r1')
txt.text := 'Hello!'

g.onEvent('close', (*) => function() {
  msgBox('Going to exit application')
  exitApp()
})

g.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fat arrow function (`() => expr`) "evaluates the sub-expression *expr* and returns the result." ([Source](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Variables.htm#fat-arrow))

The next section in the documentation states:

> Commas may be used to write multiple sub-expressions on a single line. This is most commonly used to group together multiple assignments or function calls. For example: `x:=1, y+=2, ++index, MyFunc()`. Such statements are executed in order from left to right.

---

These variants seem to work (I'm using v2.0-a108):

```
g.onEvent('close', (*) => (
  msgBox('Going to exit application')
  exitApp()
))

g.onEvent('close', (*) => (
  msgBox('Going to exit application'),
  exitApp()
))

g.onEvent('close', (*) => (msgBox('Going to exit application') exitApp()))

g.onEvent('close', (*) => (msgBox('Going to exit application'), exitApp()))
```

The comma between `msgBox()` and `exitApp()` seems to be optional in both multi-line and single-line expressions. I think that the multi-line expression is cleaner without the comma, whereas the single-line expression is more readable with the comma.

Though if you have more complex sub-expressions, some commas are required. For example, the following code won't work without the comma on the third line:

```
g.onEvent('close', (*) => (
  msgBox('Going to exit application')
  foo := 1 + 2,
  msgBox(foo)
  exitApp()
))
```

(Alternatively, you could write `(foo := 1 + 2)`, and the comma would not be required.)

I don't know if including or omitting the comma has other effects. See also: [comma performance](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Variables.htm#CommaPerf).

---

You can also combine sub-expressions with `&&` and `||`. In the following example, `exitApp()` won't be called, because `1 > 2` is `false`. Notice that parentheses around the expression are not required:

```
g.onEvent('close', (*) => msgBox('Going to exit application') && 1 > 2 && exitApp())
```

Comment: These snippets also work with version *2.0-a103-56441b52*. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.